# What's the difference between using "past participle" and "passive present participle" for describing a reason?

Tags: difference, passive-voice, past-participles, participles, present-participles

What's the difference between the two sentences?

> Being built atop lxml, Scrapy also supports xxxxx.
>
> Built atop lxml, Scrapy also supports xxxxx.

Scrapy is a computer software and it's built atop lxml (a software component). Because Scrapy is built atop lxml, it could do whatever lxml could do.

Are both the sentences appropriate?

Comment: Why do you want to use *being*? You are only stating a fact; there is no action. Anyway, if you can't explain it, don't use it.

Comment: The first with **being** attempts to emphasize a little more the meaning "*because* it is built atop lxml..."  but that sentence with **being** would not be considered good writing.  The second one is the better choice. The first would be better in a future-oriented statement:  Being built atop lxml, Scrapy *will* also support xxxx."

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct and mean more or less the same thing, but the first is not considered to be good style, particularly in "business" English.  Style guides say you should avoid the present progressive/continuous ("-ing") form of verbs where not absolutely necessary, and use instead the more direct (and less wordy) present tense.

Strunk and White "The Elements of Style" is the most common reference for this, although I'm sure others will recommend different sources (or later editions).

Example:

> In our new state-of-the-art facility, our engineers **are designing** tomorrow's technology today.
>
> In our new state-of-the-art facility, our engineers **design** tomorrow's technology today.

There's nothing wrong with the first sentence, but the second is considered better style.

(Edit) For marketing purposes there may be good reasons to use the continuous tense to give a sense of *ongoing progress*, or *immediacy* to an activity.  This might sound better on something like a prospectus, a document used to attract investors, because it suggests a rapid return on investment.